# Java InputStream to Python (PY4J)

Tags: java, python, inputstream, py4j

I'm running Java code in python using PY4J (http://py4j.sourceforge.net/).

My java function returns an InputStream and I would like to manipulate it in my python code:

Java code:

```
public InputStream getPCAP(key) {
        InputStream inputStream = cyberStore.getPCAP(pcapStringKey);
        return inputStream;
}
```

Python code:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

gateway = JavaGateway()
input_stream = PY4J_GateWay.getPCAP(key); 
...
```

How can I get the InputStream in python?

Should I convert it to something else in the java code before returning it to python?

Comment: We would need a bit more code to answer the question: the class containing getPCAP and how an instance of this class is created and accessed.

Comment: do you have any sort of benchmark comparison between sharing streams through Py4j and storing data on filesystem (even /dev/shm) and loading normal python operation ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to read from the input stream.

Java's API lets you read from an `InputStream` into a `byte` array. There is no simple way to pass a Pythonic `bytearray` by reference, yet you can easily add a method which reads from an `InputStream` and returns a `byte` array:

```
public byte[] read(InputStream stream, int count) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
    stream.read(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Then, in Python you can call this method to read from the `InputStream`:

```
gateway = JavaGateway()
input_stream = gateway.getPCAP(key)
data = gateway.read(input_stream, 1000) # reads 1000 bytes from input_stream
```