# Pyjnius custom java method returning 'JavaException: Unable to find a None Method' works after Public Static

Tags: java, python, android, kivy, pyjnius

So I needed to read a ByteArray from the InputStream in Android.  Therefore I used this [custom method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891144/java-inputstream-to-python-py4j) in java in a kivy App using pyjnius for the same reason as stated in the link.  

I placed the ReadInput.java file in this directory:
`~/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/JniusPrintBluetoothAppie/src/main/java/org/kivy/android`
I initialised the java class with pyjnius:

```
Reading = autoclass('org.kivy.android.ReadInput')
```

The java code:

```
package org.kivy.android;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.Byte;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadInput {
    public byte[] inputread(InputStream stream, int count) throws IOException {
        byte[] by = new byte[count];
        stream.read(by);
        return by;
    }
}
```

I read from the buffer in python using the following code:

```
Reading.inputread(self.recv_stream, 4) #recv_stream is an Android BluetoothAdapter createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord getInputStream object
```

But for some reason this above code constantly gave me the following error:
`JavaException: Unable to find a None Method`

After many, many days of struggle I finally got the method to work by simply declaring the method as:
`public static`
The new java method looked as follows and I called it in the same way as above:

```
package org.kivy.android;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.Byte;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadInput {
    public static byte[] inputread(InputStream stream, int count) throws IOException {
        byte[] by = new byte[count];
        stream.read(by);
        return by;
    }
}
```

What I want to know is why would the word 'static' make the java method suddenly work?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @mentallurg I added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in Python code you access the method in a *static* way:

```
Reading.inputread(...)
```

This will work only if you define the method *inputread* in Java as *static*.

But it was not necessary. It could better to keep the method as non-static in Java and to use it in Python in a normal non-static way:

```
Reading = autoclass('org.kivy.android.ReadInput')
reading = Reading()
reading.inputread(...)
```

Comment: Sorry I am not that well versed in java as I would like to be (still learning alot), but is Reading() and reading not both class objects?  Meaning the inputread method belongs to the class.  Can you please tell me what separates the two variables?

Comment: Or how does the two ways of accessing the method differ?

Comment: By calling *Reading()* you create a new *instance* (or an *object* if you wish) of that class. When you have an instance, you can call instance methods.

Comment: Okay, statically you don't need an object or instance of the class to access the method.  Non-statically you need an object or instance of the class to access the methods.  Thanks, I definitely learned something.